# error (Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <my_App.SideBarTableViewController: 0x7becd2e0>)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, swift3, xcode8

my code for calling photo gallery using UIIMAGEPICKERCONTROLLER -
Note : this code is under Side menu tabeview controller.

self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

Error :
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was on Requesting Permission for accessing user photo gallery. In iOS 10 we need add Requesting Permission Privacy Settings in info.plist. This in how i implement it https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html

Thanks.